# How to use text from html-element in others non-cypres functions?

Tags: javascript, cypress, autotest

I need to get text from html element to use it in other checking.

But this checking must be done elsewhere later, not inside function of text getting.

That's why such variant as

```
> cy.get('#at__title').invoke('text').then((storedValue) => {
>    storedValue
> })
```

doesn't suite, because I can use text only inside `then`.

Also I tried to use

```
> cy.get('#at__title').invoke('text').as('element_text')
> this.element_text
```

but console log shows `this.element_text` as undefined.

Comment: You should follow the documented approach, random variations of the syntax are not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias is correct `cy.get('#at__title').invoke('text').as('element_text')` but to access the value like this

```js
this.element_text
```

requires the test to ***not*** be an arrow function.

Use this format

```js
it('test something', function() { 
  this.element_text
```

Or use the longer syntax for accessing an alias

```js
cy.get('@element_text').then(element_text => {
```

Comment: But I already have used `function()` both in `describe` and in `it`.
https://paste.pics/8bf28b1fede259712c974f68254ca239

Comment: That's not going to work, it's in the same block and the the `cy.checkDB()` command gets it's parameter values before the above `cy.get()` finishes. In that scenario you should use a `.then()` because you are actually using the value straight after it is obtained.

Comment: You can still use the alias later in the test, but beware of closure problems like the one you describe above.

Comment: I tried to use alias, but it doesn't return text. It returns [object Object].
https://paste.pics/bf2053d3d2385520223d90fdb69c297e

Comment: Again, not going to work - it's the wrong syntax. See my example above.

Comment: Sorry, just I wrote in my question that using `then` doesn't suite, because I can use text only inside `then`.
There is not any other possibilities?